# How do I show all the images in my public:/images/ folder?

Tags: 7

So i have successfully uploaded my images into my public:/images folder now i want to output/display all of them in page how do i retrieve all the images?

here's  code by the way of handling the form.

```
 function testform($form, &$form_state) {
   $form = array();
   $form['file'] = array(
      '#type' => 'file',
      '#title' => t('Image'),
      '#description' => t('Upload a file, allowed extensions: jpg, jpeg, png, gif'),
     );
  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
     );
 return $form;
```

}

here's the code for validating it.

```
      function testform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
         $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
        'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
          ));
       if ($file) {
       if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
       $form_state['values']['file'] = $file;
    }
else {
        form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file   folder.'));
     }
  }
else {
   form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
}
```

}

here's the code for submitting.

```
    testform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
         $file=$form_state['values']['file'];
         unset($form_state['values']['file']);
         $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
         file_save($file);
         drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted and the image has been saved,   filename: @filename.', array('@filename' => $file->filename)));
          }
```

Comment: How did you uploaded the images, via "Files import" menu or via FTP?

Comment: uploaded them using file_save_upload

Comment: @DAY I've posted an answer, I used that module it works great for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer @KrishnaMohan i'll try to get all answers and i'll try them all and see what's best for my site.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply achieve that by using a module called [Filebrowser](https://www.drupal.org/project/filebrowser).

> Allows site administrators to expose a particular file system folder and all of its subfolders with a fancy FTP-like interface to site visitors. File metainformation (via descript.ion and files.bss) is supported. The module also allows these metafiles to store special content, which can be parsed with a callback. If no callback is specified in the file, only the description will be fetched.

Using this module you can display all your exported files.

Here is the sample screenshot from project page.
[image]

Hope this post helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To display all the files managed by Drupal, you can use Views.

Create a view based on files. You can add the fields related to files, i.e. Filename, rendered file, path, etc.

An export of a sample view below:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'test_files';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'file_managed';
$view->human_name = 'Test Files';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: File: Rendered File */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_file';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['display'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['view_mode'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 0;
/* Field: File: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['id'] = 'filename';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['table'] = 'file_managed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['field'] = 'filename';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$translatables['test_files'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get fid of the images and then put it in the function below Like i did:-

```
$file_load=file_load($fid);  
$url=$file_load->uri;
```

$url retrieve you image path where you have uploaded your image.
Like:- public:/images/image_name

Use this fuction to display your image. [image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)

```
$variables= array(
'style_name' => 'style_name', 
'path' => $url, 
'getsize' => FALSE, 
'attributes' => array(
 'width' => '100',
 'height' => '100')
);

echo theme('image_style',$variables);
```

Note :-if you are using drupal theme('image_style',$variables) function to display image.then put url like public:/images/image_name in path given above.else you are using  to display image then use below code.

Or You can also do this.

```
$file_url=file_create_url($url); 
echo '<img src="'.$file_url.'"'>;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: do i have to change the uri to public://?

Comment: I have write a note in above answer...please check...

Comment: i used  theme('image_style',$variables) but it is not showing the images only a box. followed your instructions

Comment: Have you put style name in place of style_name.

Comment: firstly put any valid static fid and then check it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module, to import all the media contents you have uploaded into your site.

1. First download and install the module.
2. Now, navigate to

   Content » Media

   `example.com/admin/content/media`

[image]

Here, you can add your new files to media or simply import from your directory location.

[image]

Usage:

You will need to add a field to your content type with the widget type "Media file selector", this will bring up the your media selecting window.

[image]

[Demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7s90s--Eo0)